# Security best pratices, how to deny rest api connections that don't belong to dedicated client

Tags: javascript, security, server, client

Is there a way to handshake server/client?

Im aware of security tokens, but how often they should updated, and what should trigger that? Isn't calling DB to update tokens often a expensive operation? (i dont know how they work at all)

Can someone give me a hand on how should an implementation of that should work?

If not possible in react-native, nodejs and mysql, an explanation in in meta-code would be already helpfull.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to verify each request from a specific client such as ensuring that CompanyX can use your service but anonymous users can't just access it by knowing the address? I don't normally ask for clarification, but I'm trying to understand what you'd like to achieve with this. Could you tell me what you imagine the end result would look like?

Comment: Yes! That's it! At the moment, even a postman client can communicate to my server! I wish to only allow dedicated client to make requests, so a malicious user can't access my routes and post to my DB so easy.

Comment: A postman client could also comunicate, if have the "security token".